# C++ Code skips over code and Professor can't figure it out

Tags: c++

This program is made to take in input into an array of test values, sort them, add them, and take the average. It will take up to 100 variables and uses a negative value to escape from the input loop.

I talked to my professor, and after about 30 minutes or so, he still couldn't find the error. He put in a few for loops to print out the array, but it skips them and prints out the total and average statements.

The problem is that when I compile and run the program, (depending on what compiler I use) I get strange answers for total and average and it skips over outputting the array. This can be fixed by simply making the call to the sort function a comment (or deleting it, of course), but that is a requirement.

For example, Ideone.com gives me Total=0 and Average= -nan.

Visual studio gave me nothing for average and a strange answer for total.

```
//Programmed by Chandler McLean
//Week 8 Test Scores Lab
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
void round(int);
void sortArray(int[ ], int);
int main()
{
  int nums[100] = {0};
  int x = 0, count = 0;
  double z = 0, avg = 0, total = 0;
  cout << "Please enter up to 100 test scores.\nNegative values will terminate program.\nValues above 100 will not be accepted.\n";
  do {
    cin >> x;
    cout << "I just read " << x << endl;
    if (x < 0) {
      break;
    }
    if (x > 100) {
      cout << "Please, tests between 0 and 100 only.\n";
      continue;
    }
    nums[count] = x;
    count++;
  } while (count < 100);

  cout << "...after the loop" << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    cout << " array element " << i << " is " << nums[i]  << endl;

  sortArray(nums, count);    // pass array of 20 ints


  for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
    total = total + nums[i];
  }
  cout << "\nThe total is: " << total;
  avg = total / count;
  cout << "\nThe average is: " << avg;
  system("pause");
}




void sortArray(int nums[], int count) //store array addr & size
{
  int hold, a, b;               // a and b are subscripts
  for (a = 0; a < count - 1; a++) //start first loop with 0
  {
    for (b = a + 1; b < count; b++) //start second loop with 1
    {
      if (nums[a] > nums[b])    //compare nums[0] to nums[1]
      {
        hold = nums[a];        // if first is bigger
        nums[a] = nums[b];     // swap the two
        nums[b] = hold;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "C++ Code skips over code and Proffesor can't figure it out" it's funny title.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Professor skips rocks?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjSjNhI8aYc)

Comment: the for loop which sums the total should be: for(int i=0;i<count;++i) since count already reflects the number of entries in the array. your current code has count-1 which is going to exclude the last valid entry from the total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it must be hard for your professor to figure out the correct size of array.

```
for (int i=0; i<count; i++){ //not count-1
        total=total+nums[i];
       }
       cout<<"\nThe total is: "<<total; 
       avg=total/count; 
       cout<<"\nThe average is: "<<avg;
       system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: @Michael Watson: That actually fixed it all. It runs just fine now... I just can't accept the answer for three minutes. I can't believe we both missed that.

Comment: I crosschecked before posting.it fixes the avg/total problem.

Comment: Anyway, I guess you can format your code a bit better